# Bootstrap 4 supports LESS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

As nowadays bootstrap team announced the version 4 alpha which natively uses SASS as CSS preprocessor. Is this mean it hasn't any LESS support?!

Comment: Yes, Less version of Boostrap is no longer planned for v4. (It's just a matter of peope willing to contribute to such version. Main Bootstrap developers seems to be tied to SCSS much more with their other development involvements so it's actually not that surprising move).

Comment: I recommend this port: https://github.com/seanCodes/bootstrap-less-port.  I'm using it on a personal site and I haven't run into any issues, and I know the author and he'd be open to any contributions that help preserve 1:1 utility and output.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to remember that Bootstrap 4 is in its Alpha phase. Currently it does not support LESS, as Bootstrap's [blog entry on Bootstrap 4 Alpha](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/08/19/bootstrap-4-alpha/) states:

> **Moved from Less to Sass.** Bootstrap now compiles faster than ever thanks to Libsass, and we join an increasingly large community of Sass developers.

<s>*However*, version 4's [Getting Started page](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#package-managers) does still give LESS a mention (although I imagine this is a copy/paste oversight):</s>

> ### npm
>
> Bootstrap’s package.json contains some additional metadata under the following keys:
>
> - `less` - path to Bootstrap’s main Less source file
> - `style` - path to Bootstrap’s non-minified CSS that’s been precompiled using the default settings (no customization)

Whether it will support LESS in the future cannot be really determined without some form of official *yay* or *nay*, but currently it doesn't look like there are any plans involving it.

Answer (score 10):

The Bootstrap team decided not to include a Less version with the v4.0 launch but there is an unofficial [Bootstrap 4 Less port](https://github.com/seanCodes/bootstrap-less-port) available. (Full disclosure: I’m the author.)

Hopefully they will have an official Less port like they did for Sass in the future.

Comment: Member of the Less team here, and I've used the Less port linked, and it works fantastically.