# Problems compiling css from bootstrap 4 less port using winless

Tags: bootstrap-4, less

Hi a comment from one of the bootstrap authors at [Bootstrap 4 supports LESS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374863/bootstrap-4-supports-less) suggests that seancodes' less port of Bootstrap 4 works perfectly, but I am experiencing problems.

I have downloaded the latest version and copied across the less files to my own less directory, but when I try to compile a .css stylesheet, I get errors. I am using the latest version of winless 1.9.1 on a windows 10 pc.

Initially, I received a parse error relating to all the mentions of '@plugin' in _functions.less. These appeared to be resolved when I added a colon to read '@plugin:' to each.

But then I started to receive other errors such as:

> SyntaxError: CSS guard can only be used at the end of selector in
>   …\less\mixins_buttons.less on line 94, column 36:

This relates to the line:

> & when (@enable-shadows) and not (@btn-active-box-shadow = ~"" ) {

it appears to be resolved by replacing the double quotes with single ones on both line 94 and then on a similar one just below (line 96), but then I get a parse error:

> ParseError Unrecognised input in …\less\mixins_forms.less on line 56,
>   column 19  56 was-validated &:@{state},

From googling around, it seems that this might be something to do with string interpolation and escaping strings, or perhaps listing function inputs as comma separated values but I don't really understand what this means or what to do about it.

Does anyone have any idea what I have done wrong or need to do get this right?

Comment: actually, removing the quotes altogether created the last error, not replacing double quotes with single ones. Apologies.

Comment: As far as I understand the Bootstrap port requires Less 3.x. Winless 1.9.1 (released about 5 years ago) ships with Less 2.1. (There's option to use [external Less compiler copy](https://github.com/marklagendijk/WinLess#using-a-globally-installed-less) - but I have no idea how compatible it is with recent versions).